# Parsing text from .txt files

Tags: parsing, awk

I've a tabbed log file but I need only few chracters of the line marked 30.10 in the beginning.

Using the command
    awk '/^30.10/{print}' FOOD_ORDERS_201907041307.DEL

i get this output
    30.1006   35470015000205910002019070420190705                                             00000014870000000034

```
30.1006   35470015000205900002019070420190705                                             00000014890000000029

30.1006   35470023000205920002019070420190705                                             00000014900000000011
```

What i need to extract is 3547 and the last nth caracthers from the very end after zeros.
So, expected output will be:
3547
34
29
11
But if the last 10 caracthers contains leading zeros and a number, i need that number

Comment: You made this question about as confusing and hard to understand as possible. If you don't want to match just 2 chars then don't say that you do. If your input can contain 1143 or any other number with greater than 2 chars then include an example of that in your sample input/output. If your output should contain 3547 then show that in your expected output rather than as a separate statement at the end. Etc..

Comment: Given input of `30.1006   30470023000205920002019070420190705                                             00000010890000001050` what should the output be and why? Include that in the sample input/output in your question. I suspect your fields actually contain fixed-width sub-fields rather than being separated by zeros. If they truly are separated by chains of zeros as you suggest but can themselves contain zeros then idk how you'll identify the substrings you want to output.

Comment: Output should be: 
3047
1050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is unclear, your answer to Ed Morton's comment provides a bit more clarity on what you are trying to achieve. Where it is still unclear is just exactly you want from the third field. From your question and the various comments, it appears if the line begins with `30.10` you want the first `4-digits` from second field and you want the rightmost digits that are `[1-9]` from the third field.

If that accurately captures what you need, then `awk` with a combination of `substr`, `match` and `length` string functions can isolate the digits you are interested in. For example:

```
awk '/^30.10/ { 
    l=match ($3, /[1-9]+$/)
    print substr ($2, 1, 4) " " substr ($3, l, length($3)-l+1)
}' test
```

Would take the input file (borrowed from Dudi Boy's answer), e.g.

```
$ cat test
30.1006 35470015000205910002019070420190705 00000014870000000034
30.1006 35470015000205900002019070420190705 00000014890000001143
30.1006 35470015000205900002019070420190705 00000014890000000029
30.1006 35470023000205920002019070420190705 00000014900000000011
```

and return to you:

```
3547 34
3547 1143
3547 29
3547 11
```

Let me know if that accurately captures what you need.

Comment: First and foremost, my apologies for being unclear with my request. I will try to be more clear posting next question in the future.

Answer by David C. Rankin suits accurately my request. I just made one change to the codem putting $1 instead of test in the script.

This way i can pass dynamically a file to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `awk` script to do the task:

`script.awk`

```
/^30.10/ {    # for each line starting with 30.10
    last2chars = substr($3, length($3)-1);  # extract last 2 chars from 3rd field into variable last2chars
    if($3 ~ /00001143$/) last2chars = 1143; # if 3rd field ends with 1143, update variable last2chars respectively
    print last2chars;  # output variable last2chars
}
```

`input.txt`

```
30.1006 35470015000205910002019070420190705 00000014870000000034
30.1006 35470015000205900002019070420190705 00000014890000001143
30.1006 35470015000205900002019070420190705 00000014890000000029
30.1006 35470023000205920002019070420190705 00000014900000000011
```

running:

```
 awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

outupt:

```
34
1143
29
11
```

Comment: I think OP means get characters after last 0. Not literally get 1143 if it ends 1143... In fact they say that explicitly *"the last nth caracthers from the end after zeros."*

Comment: I agree with DudiBoy 's reading of the Q. @FrancescoCicciuzz , do you see why it is important to include expected output given your sample input? ;-) . Good luck to all.

Answer (score -2):

GOT Part of it!
awk '/^30.10/{print}' FOOD_ORDERS_201907041307.DEL | sed 's/.*(..)/\1/'